# Is it possible to add multiple rows in one field in a database using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, mysqli

So my problem is that I want to add multiple members in one team, but I cannot seem to figure out how or whether if it is even possible to do so. Here is my code for you to get my question.

```
<?php

     $tname = $_POST['tname'];
     $maxnum = $_POST['maxnum'];
     $host = "localhost";
     $sqluname = "root";
     $sqlpass = "";
     $db = "teams";
     $tablename = "team info";
     $mem1 = $_POST['mem1'];
     $mem2 = $_POST['mem2'];
     $mem3 = $_POST['mem3'];
     $mem4 = $_POST['mem4'];
     $connect = mysqli_connect("$host","$sqluname","$sqlpass","$db") ;

         if(mysqli_connect_errno())
                        {
                        echo "Problem". mysqli_connect_error();
                        }


    $sql = "INSERT INTO teaminfo (TeamName,MaxNum,Members)
    VALUES
    ('$tname','$maxnum','$mem1')";

    /* Inside Members, I would like to add more than just $mem1, like $mem2, $mem3, $mem4.
    */

        if(!mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){

        die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($connect));

        }


        echo "Team is added";
        mysqli_close($connect);
        header("location: TeamDummyClient.html");
    ?>
```

Comment: I am new to this site, so I dont know if my code can show or not. Let me know what to do if you can't see it. Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Edited to show your code. Also, you are wide open to SQL injections. Definitely fix that before publishing this code to production.

Comment: Its better to use a `relation` with a `foreign` key between `Team` and `TeamInfo`.

Comment: @Romio This is terrible idea, and violates 3NF. See normalization

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the violation of 3NF. I am new to MySQL and this is my first database to create. Looks like I need to do some extra research. But thanks for the help, it is greatly appreciated.And thank you John Conde for bringing that issue to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO teaminfo (TeamName,MaxNum,Members) VALUES";
 $sql .= "('$tname','$maxnum','$mem1'),";
 $sql .= "('$tname','$maxnum','$mem2'),";
 $sql .= "('$tname','$maxnum','$mem3'),";
 $sql .= "('$tname','$maxnum','$mem4')";
```

You should be escaping the strings before you insert their values to prevent SQL injections. Here's an example for one of the rows:

```
$sql .= "(
    '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($tname) . "',
    '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($maxnum) . "',
    '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mem1) . "'
),";
```

Comment: Why all the stopping and starting? Also - I think you've missed the point of the question - or else I have!!

Comment: Hey Strawberry, so we meet again. What stopping and starting are you talking about ? Just keep in mind that this is new to me :D